# Trocar vh por px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou tendo o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma página que tem vários slides em HTML mesmo. Todos esses slides tem seu tamanho definido por `vh` ao invés de `pixel`.

O problema é que quando vou acessar com mobile, o celular ficando na horizontal tudo bem, mas quando coloco na vertical ele não exibe o slide que eu estava, ele faz o recalculo do `vh`, devido a mudança de orientação do celular, e passa para o slide seguinte.

Primeiramente eu pensei em desabilitar a transição de tela do celular via javascript, mas parece ser *gambi*.

Tem como eu ver se o site esta sendo acessado por mobile e executar uma função em javascript para que ele substitua tudo que tiver `vh` para `pixel`?

Não sei se essa é a melhor opção, se alguém tiver uma sugestão fico muito grato.

Answer (score 2):

Trocar VH por Pixels tem sim, por Media Queries. Seria uma forma de aplicar estilos quando o usuário acessar o conteúdo de um aparelho diferente. Este é um exemplo básico que você deve procurar saber mais a fundo.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Esse CSS diz que quando o usuário acessar o seu site à partir de um navegador que tenha tela menor do que 480px, o `body` terá 100px de largura. Com um pouco de pesquisa e trabalho você pode adaptar isso à sua necessidade.

A grande questão é se tem uma outra forma preferível de resolver a sua situação.

Comment: Você mencionou sobre ter "100px", mas no exemplo o width do body passou a ter 500px (e ultrapassando o limite da media querie, que no caso seria 480px). Dê uma corrigida!

Comment: @ThiagoBarros Valeu o toque. Corrigido.